# Powershell LastWriteTime each item that is matched using select-string -pattern

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

Attempting to look though a list of files and parse out the phone numbers using regex in powershell, but I also want to include the LastWriteTime of each file

I am currently using this but it seems to only pull the Date info I need from the first match

```
$loc = Read-Host "Enter location"
dir $loc *.xml | 
Select-String -pattern '\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}' -AllMatches |
% {$_.Matches} |
Select @{n='    Date   Time    ';e={(get-item $loc).LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')}}, @{n=' Phone Number';e={$_.Value}} |
ft -AutoSize
```

Which results in

```
Date   Time         Phone Number 
------------------- ------------- 
07/07/2015 04:27:32 (555) 555-1234
07/07/2015 04:27:32 (555) 555-2234
07/07/2015 04:27:32 (555) 555-3234
07/07/2015 04:27:32 (555) 555-4234
```

Any ideas on this would be great

Solution provided by @Matt

```
 dir $loc *.xml | Select-String -pattern '\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}' -AllMatches | Select @{n='    Date   Time    ';e={(get-item $_.Path).LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')}}, @{n=' Phone Number ';e={$($_.Matches).Value}} |ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: What if you use `get-item $_.Path`? Its the full file path property of the matched line. Also you don't really need to artificially space the property name for `date time`

Comment: @Matt thanks for the suggestion but if I use $_.Path or $_ it returns nothing at all

Comment: I had the right approach but applied incorrectly.. I will make a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to clean up the code but I removed the inner foreach loop and added the property I intended.

```psh
$loc = Read-Host "Enter location"
dir $loc *.xml | 
Select-String -pattern '\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}' -AllMatches |
Select @{n='Date Time';e={(get-item $_.Path).LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')}}, @{n=' Phone Number';e={$_.Matches.Value}} |
ft -AutoSize
```

The matches objects have a path property that represents the full file path of the matched line. I used dot notation for the value of the match which requires at least PowerShell 3.0. If you don't have that its easy to address.

Comment: Excellent, just about exactly what I was in the middle of writing when I got distracted by work. Stupid work... Don't forget the `<!-- language: lang-psh -->` or `<!-- language-all: lang-psh -->` for code prettification =)

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Work sucks. I added the prettification for _you_ but I already saw it on the answer and the question so I didnt bother

Comment: Huh, I wasn't seeing it. It was probably just something on my end.